# How to get Chrome Extension Fired a function when re-enabled from disable state?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

This is My code inside background.js

```
chrome.runtime.onStartup.addListener(function(details) {
    Doing();
    setInterval(function(){ Doing("Refresh",localStorage["Toogle"]) }, 10 * 60 * 1000); //Minute * Second * Milisecond
    console.log("StartedUp");
});

chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(function(details) {
    Doing();
    setInterval(function(){ Doing("Refresh",localStorage["Toogle"]) }, 10 * 60 * 1000); //Minute * Second * Milisecond
    console.log("Installed");
});
```

I already have chrome.runtime.onStartup dan onInstalled. So My Function will fired after Install the extension and when browser open fresh.

But The Problem is when my extension is disabled and enabled by user, my setInteval is not firing again. So I think i need to make running the setInteval when the extension is re-enabled by user.

Is there any someway to to that ? Or can i make my extension can't be disabled ?

Comment: If you don't use `"persistent": false` in manifest.json, you can simply put the code at the start of the script.

Comment: ah so I just need to setInterval outside the function onetime... So Background.js run in when enable that... right ?